# Book suggestions for a basic introduction to Syntactic Cartography?

Tags: syntax, reference-request, generative-grammar

I am interested in learning more about Syntactic Cartography and its basic concepts. Can anyone recommend a book or resource that provides a solid introduction to this topic? I have a background in linguistics and I am familiar with some of the basic concepts of Generative Grammar and the theories proposed by Chomsky, such as Government and Binding (G&B), but I'm relatively new to the field of Syntactic Cartography, so I'm looking for something that is beginner-friendly.

I would appreciate any suggestions for books that cover the fundamental principles and techniques of Syntactic Cartography, along with clear explanations and examples. Ideally, the book should offer a comprehensive overview and serve as a starting point for further exploration in this area.

Thank you in advance for your recommendations!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartographic_syntax https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/38640/chapter/335348312